# Scipy.detrend: Function changes range of values

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scipy

I am trying to detrend this one dimensional array:

```
array([13.64352283, 13.48914862, 13.00767009, 13.35416524, 13.60143818,
       13.40895156, 13.48349417, 13.65703125, 13.4959721 , 13.28891263,
       12.97999066, 13.01112397, 12.79519705, 13.32030445, 13.19949068,
       12.88691975, 13.32079707])
```

The function runs without errors but changes the range of values from ~[12,14] to ~[-0.4,0.4].
I believe it is due to the small std dev of the values that this happens.
Any ideas how to fix this, so I can plot the array with trend and the detrended one into one plot?
Normalization is not an option.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that is exactly what [detrend](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.detrend.html) does: it subtracts the values of the least square linear approximation to the input.

Here is a plot to illustrate what happens:

```py
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array([13.64352283, 13.48914862, 13.00767009, 13.35416524, 13.60143818,
              13.40895156, 13.48349417, 13.65703125, 13.4959721, 13.28891263,
              12.97999066, 13.01112397, 12.79519705, 13.32030445, 13.19949068,
              12.88691975, 13.32079707])
plt.plot(y, color='dodgerblue')
plt.plot(signal.detrend(y), color='limegreen')
plt.plot(y - signal.detrend(y), color='crimson')
plt.show()
```

The red line in the plot is the linear approximation that got subtracted from the original data to obtain `detrend(y)`.

[image: plot of detrend]